# Add customisation text to shopify using custom liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, personalization

I want to add the a Personalisation text line (max 4 characters) to some of my shopify products, so the client can specify initials for embroidery, also need this info to carry through to the shopping cart etc for us.

I have seen examples of adding code to the product.liquid file but i dont have this i only have product.json, so i wonder if this can be added using custom liquid.

Can the same principle be used to add fabric care icons (png images) to the product descriptions?

Thanks

I have tried some liquid code snippets i found but they allow multi lines of text and i only want one line.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.